# How to access group policy of a Windows server 2019 Active Directory DC?

Tags: group-policy, domain-controller, windows-server-2019

Before I enable AD DC in my Windows server 2019, I had modified some objects in group policy editor (gpedit), but after turning the server into an active directory domain controller, i don't know how to access the local gpedit anymore. mmc.exe doesn't work.

I know how to use the new group policy management to set policies for other computers in my domain, but I don't know how to set policies for my own server AND access previous modified group policy settings of the server before it was turned into an AD DC.

[image]

my problem is exactly this. i don't want my server to trust all hosts

[image]

there is * in there and the source is a GPO but all 3 of my group policies show this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

so as you can see they are all set to not configured and i can't find the source of that *

when i type mmc.exe in run in server i get this:

[image]

I'm logged in as the Administrator into the server.

How can i fix this?

Comment: To identify the source of a policy, run `gpresult /h gpresult.html` from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: @GregAskew it says the winning GPO is Local Group Policy. how do i access  Local Group Policy now? I posted all the screenshots above

Comment: From an elevated command prompt, `gpedit.msc`

Comment: @GregAskew oh gosh thank you very much! it was my fault. i was typing "gpedit" in the run instead of "gpedit.msc" . i probably thought it's like "regedit" that doesn't need the ".msc" extension. if you want you can post it as answer to accept it. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify the source of a policy, run `gpresult /h gpresult.html` from an elevated command prompt.

To view configured policy, from an elevated command prompt, `gpedit.msc`